# Using parentheses in Python LDAP's search

Tags: python, ldap

I am trying to perform use `LDAPObject.search_s()` with a search filter.

This works perfectly fine when I have a parameter without `()`s but this fails when a `()` exists in the filter.

For example when I look for a group with

`"(name=(Test Group))"`, a `ldap.FILTER_ERROR` will be raised, but when I use `"(name=Test Group)"` as a filter, there will be no issues.

How do I search for groups that have parens?

> Reference:
>
> http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap.html?highlight=initialize#ldap-objects

Comment: How can a name be equal to "(Test Group)"?

Comment: It can. `cn==` is also a valid name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Section 3 of RFC4515][1] says that parenthesis (*parenthèses*) and other special chars must be escaped.

> The  rule ensures that the entire filter string is a valid UTF-8 string and provides that the octets that represent the ASCII characters "*" (ASCII 0x2a), "(" (ASCII 0x28), ")" (ASCII 0x29), "" (ASCII 0x5c), and NUL (ASCII 0x00) are represented as a backslash "" (ASCII 0x5c) followed by the two hexadecimal digits representing the value of the encoded octet.

Python makes encoding easy. Just escape the special char with a backslash (`\`). Searching for a group named "test group", your search filter will be :

```
'(cn=\(test group\))'
```

(tested with python-ldap version 2.4.10 with an OpenLDAP server)
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515

Answer (score 8):

You should use the ldap.filter module.  It already contains all the rules for things that need to be escaped.

```
>>> import ldap.filter
>>> ldap.filter.filter_format('(cn=%s)', ['(Test Group)',])
'(cn=\\28Test Group\\29)'
```